# Set OpenTelemetry span service name in Go

Tags: go, open-telemetry

I use https://pkg.go.dev/go.opentelemetry.io/otel/trace library and want to change the service name of a span, which I get from other service, but it doesn't work.

I tried the two approaches:

```
_, span := tracer.Start(r.Context(), "http://api2:8001/monitoring")
span.SetAttributes(attribute.String("service.name", "api2"))
defer span.End()
```

```
_, span := tracer.Start(r.Context(), "http://api2:8001/monitoring")
span.SetName("api2")
defer span.End()
```

I write traces to the Grafana, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ej4Cy.png) you can see, that the service name is api instead of api2.

Comment: Have you tried changing the span name on init vs setting the attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Service Name should be set at trace provider level instead of span level.
e.g: https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/go/manual/

```golang
traceRes, err := resource.New(ctx,
    resource.WithAttributes(semconv.ServiceNamespaceKey.String("api2")),
)

traceProvider := trace.NewTracerProvider(
    trace.WithResource(traceRes),
)
```